# Background image height issue on div

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a div with a background image applied to it (#wrapper) and the first child of the div is an absolute positioned color overlay div (.bg-overlay) For some reason whenever I have this .bg-overlay div it doesn't seem to allow my background image to grow in height when other elements are placed within it.

I am trying to simply apply some bottom padding to a p tag within this #wrapper but it seems to just overflow it when looking at the inspect tool. I dont quite understand why the main #wrapper div isnt growing in height. I have set a min-height to it of 200px. I'm sure its something very simple that im missing here. Appreciate any help, here is my markup.

```css
#wrapper {
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.bg-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(75, 78, 83, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#content-wrap p {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-overlay">
  <div id="content-wrap">
  <h1>
  Heading Heading Heading
  </h1>
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is the intent of this overlay? I'm not understanding it's purpose.

Comment: it's just a color overlay i am using on a background-image as the i want the image to be a little darker thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#wrapper` is not going to grow as you add content to `.bg-overlay` because it is absolute positioned. Which means it's taken out of the normal document flow and doesn't take up space. As far as `#wrapper` is concerned it's empty and doesn't have any height.

You'll have to move your content out of `.bg-overlay` or not use absolute positioning on it so that `#wrapper` will adjust as you add content. You could also use a pseudo element to create the overlay. That way you can simplify your markup a bit.

`position: relative;` and `z-index: 5;` on `#content-wrap` elevates it above the pseudo element so it isn't also under the overlay.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

#wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: rgba(75, 78, 83, 0.6);
}

#content-wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

#content-wrap p {
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
  <div id="content-wrap">
  
    <h1>
      Heading Heading Heading
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is great, good idea with the use of the pseudo element as well. Thank you very much for pointing out my error and offering that solution much appreciated.

Comment: @rufus just an FYI, my first code snippet had an error, but it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you have all your content inside the `absolute` positioned `div` and absolute elements are out of the flow that's why your container doesn't grow.

Close the tag of your **overlay** div and set on your `content-wrap` a higher `z-index`

```css
#wrapper {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.bg-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(75, 78, 83, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#content-wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

#content-wrap p {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <h1>
      Heading Heading Heading
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks so much! makes perfect sense. Closing the .bg-overlay tag straight away did the trick. Now everything is looking right, cant believe i missed that. Thanks again for your help very much appreciated.

Comment: Np glad to help you @rufus don't forget the z-index part that will make your text over the overlay

Answer (score 0):

Your p tag is within the bg-overlay div (which is positioned absolute) not within the #wrapper section.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this CSS, it should work, if you write some text, the box will grow ;)

```css
  #wrapper {
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.bg-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(75, 78, 83, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```